# Can I install Linksys WRT610N V1 firmware from a USB drive?

Tags: wireless-router

My Linksys WRT610N V1 has stopped working - the power light keeps flashing. The Cisco website says:

> A blinking power LED on your Linksys access point means the firmware
>   is corrupted or is not loading correctly. To resolve this, follow the
>   instructions below.
>
> 1. Resetting the Access Point.
> 2. Updating the Access Point’s Firmware.

Resetting didn't work and I can't upgrade the firmware via the web interface or tftp because I can't ping the router.

Does anyone know if there's any way of:

1. Loading the firmware onto a USB drive.
2. Possibly renaming the file if required.
3. Plugging the USB drive into the router.
4. Booting the router.
5. The bootloader recognises the file and loads the firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT610N

Here is your driver for the router.

> To flash the router using Microsoft Windows:
>   Open a command prompt.
>   Change to the directory containing the original Linksys firmware to use for this boot, or the DD-WRT firmware you want to install, whose size must be less than 3 MB (this example assumes that the firmware file name is code.bin).
>   Then enter the following commands:
>   arp -s 192.168.1.1  aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff
>   ping 192.168.1.1
>   tftp -i 192.168.1.1 PUT code.bin code.bin

If your router really isn't pingable:

> If the router isn't pingable anymore, there is little else you can do, but using a JTAG cable. For a pin-out see OpenWRT wiki. Then download the HairyDairyMaid Debrick Utility. Or...try the updated TJTAG program which includes the Newer Router Models.
>   solder the JTAG cable following the above linked pin-out.
>   solder a 12 pin header on the PCB of the router.
>   to install the giveio.sys copy giveio.sys and loaddrv.exe into {windows}\system32\drivers (*usually C:\windows\system32\drivers*)
>   double click loaddrv.exe in the system32 dir. This is important.
>   append the filename giveio.sys onto the path in the utility
>   press the load button and the start button, they should both confirm success. If this does not happen go no further, go back and fix this.
>   make sure interrupts are enabled on the LPT1 port - go into the device manager>LPT1>Properties>Port Settings and check "Use any interrupt assigned to this port"
>   from the command prompt cd to your Hairy Dairy directory and run wrt54g.exe to get a list of options
>   to check your cable, plugin and power up the router and do wrt54g -probeonly
>   it will then detect the CPU type. If not then check your cable.
>   finally to erase your NVRAM (the usual cause of the problem) wrt54g -erase:nvram
>   if that didn't work, erase the kernel (firmware): wrt54g -erase:kernel Now reflash the kernel via TFTP.
>   if you still have no luck, you need to erase your CFE, but make sure you have a working cfe.bin for your router model! wrt54g -erase:cfe After that you have to reflash your CFE: wrt54g -flash:cfe

If that didn't work i recommend you check out this website:

> http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_Bad_Flash#Linksys_Firmware